# How to get the id of an attached Trello ticket in the API

Tags: trello

I want to programatically find and access trello ticket `B` that is an attachment to ticket `A`.

So, I have the id of ticket `A`, and I retrieve the attachments by calling `https://developers.trello.com/reference#cardsidattachments`

However, in the response, if the attachment `B` is itself a Trello card, I only get the shortURL for `B`.

How do I get the id of `B` so I can retrieve the details of `B` using `https://developers.trello.com/reference#cardsid` ?

Is there a way to get the id of `B` from the shortURL?

Comment: BTW, through the web, I can certainly do this, by going to `shortUrl+'.json'` - but then I need to be logged in, and can't use the API for this.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what you want is to get `id` from URL. As far as I know, it's not possible. In my case I solved it via another request like this.

```
function main() {
  for(let i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    input[i] = input[i][0].slice(0, 29);  //takes short url
    let target = input[i] + '.json';

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", target);
    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
      if(this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(json['id']);
        ...
```

`input` is Trello URLs that you want to know its `id`s.